# When hiding a View ARC release it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I actually try to change my Applications to support ARC (no, this is not NDA) but there I've a problem:

for animations i set first the alpha of the view to 0, then I add it as a Subview. After Adding I make the animation.

But when I've active ARC, the View gets released when I set the alpha of the view to 0, or when I hide the View.

Is there a way to hide the view, that ARC doesn't release the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add it as a subview, the superview will take ownership and the view itself will not be released. You could also add an instance variable or `@property` and assign it there, to keep  another reference, but I don't think you need to.

Comment: If I create a instance Variable it works, bevore I added it to the subview, and then in the animation I set the alpha to 1 with searching the View in the Subviews of the viewController.